# Cannot get Custom NSObject to initialize or use properties under iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have made a *very* simple NSObject:

*GameSetUpData.h*

```
@interface GameSetUpData : NSObject

@property (readwrite, nonatomic)    NSUInteger      numberOfPlayers;
@property (strong, nonatomic)       NSMutableArray  *playerNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic)       NSString        *gameType;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic)    NSUInteger      numberOfMinutes;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic)    NSUInteger      numberOfTurns;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic)    CGSize          boardSize;

@end
```

*GameSetUpData.m*

```
#import "GameSetUpData.h"

@implementation GameSetUpData

@synthesize numberOfPlayers = _numberOfPlayers;
@synthesize playerNames = _playerNames;
@synthesize gameType = _gameType;
@synthesize numberOfMinutes = _numberOfMinutes;
@synthesize numberOfTurns = _numberOfTurns;
@synthesize boardSize = _boardSize;

@end
```

This class basically just holds data. I then try to use this object in my viewcontroller:

*MainMenu.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class GameSetUpData;

@interface MainMenu : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) GameSetUpData *gameSetUp;

-(IBAction)tappedNewGame:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)tappedTwoPlayers:(id)sender;
...
```

*MainMenu.m*

```
#import "MainMenu.h"
#import "MJViewController.h"
#import "GameSetUpData.h"

@implementation MainMenu
@synthesize gameSetUp = _gameSetUp;

...

-(IBAction)tappedTwoPlayers:(id)sender {
    _gameSetUp.numberOfPlayers = 2;
    NSLog(@"number of Players: %d", _gameSetUp.numberOfPlayers);
}
```

Unfortunately, my NSLog says that numberOfPlayers is equal to 0. What is wrong with my GameSetUpData? I was told that in iOS5 we do not need to call alloc/init or make a dealloc method. Do I still need a `-(void)init` method in GameSetUpData. Thank you all for your time!

**Edit: Please alloc/init your objects -- ARC ONLY deals with release/retain/autorelease. You still need to make an instance of an Object! I apologize for the mis-information. I will make sure to RTFM next time...**

Comment: Who ever told you that is a liar. You have to alloc and init, you just dont have to retain or release/autorelease with ARC

Comment: I apologize ColdLogic, in no way was I attempting to spread mis-information, it seemed very cagey to expect that objects do not use alloc/init anymore. I probably should of tried this prior to asking a question here, I am just astounded at how different iOS5 is from iOS4. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you have to alloc/init your object. How should the compiler know when to do that? With ARC you just don't need to retain or release.

Add `_gameSetUp = [[GameSetUpData alloc] init];` somewhere.